# JUnit test with GIN injection, without GWTTestCase and overloading gin modules?

Tags: gwt, junit, guice, gwt-gin, jukito

I designed a new project using Guice/Gin so I could make our code more modular and swap-able especially when testing.

However, I am not able to find out how to make this work in practice. I was under the impression that I could just create a new Gin/Guice module in my test and install my 'base' module, overloading any bindings that I want to replace with specific testing implementations.

I don't want to have to use GWTTestCase and load my entire module, because it is very slow and unecissary for the types of granular testing I need to do.

I have tried using Jukito (http://code.google.com/p/jukito/), gwt-test-utils (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/wiki/HowToUseWithGIN) and also some resources on doing this with guice (http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2011/03/27/junit-tests-easy-guice/).

None of these methods are yielding any results.

I think the Guice approach might work, if I defined a mirror guice module for my Gin module. However I really don't want to have to manage both of these. I really just want to test my GIN module like I would assume people test with Guice.

I feel like this should be really simple, can anyone point me to examples that work?

**Update**

Another way of looking at this question is:

How do I get the examples on the Jukito site (http://code.google.com/p/jukito/) work when the classes I am injecting are in an exernal Gin module?

**Update - In reference to Thomas Boyer's answer **

Thanks for the hint Tom, I was not able to find examples of using the adapter but I tried augmenting the Jukito examples to use the GinModuleAdapter anyway:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class MyGinTest {

  public static class Module extends JukitoModule {
    protected void configureTest() {
        install(new GinModuleAdapter(new ClientModule()));
    }
  }

  @Test
  @Inject
  public void testAdd(SyncedDOMModel mod){
      assertNotNull(mod);
  }
}
```

When I tried to run this test I recieved this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: should never be actually called
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.adapter.GwtDotCreateProvider.get(GwtDotCreateProvider.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:179)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.ensureInjector(JukitoRunner.java:118)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.computeTestMethods(JukitoRunner.java:177)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.validateInstanceMethods(JukitoRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.jukito.JukitoRunner.<init>(JukitoRunner.java:72)
```

My gin module is part of a GWTP project, and looks like this:

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new DefaultModule(ClientPlaceManager.class));

        bindPresenter(MainPagePresenter.class, MainPagePresenter.MyView.class,
                MainPageView.class, MainPagePresenter.MyProxy.class);

        bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(NameTokens.main);

        bindPresenterWidget(MapTreePresenter.class,
                MapTreePresenter.MyView.class, MapTreeView.class);

        bindPresenterWidget(MapTreeItemPresenter.class,
                MapTreeItemPresenter.MyView.class, MapTreeItemView.class);

        bind(ResourcePool.class).to(DefferredResourcePool.class);

        bind(WebSocket.class).to(WebSocketImpl.class);

    }

}
```

As you can somewhat see, the class I am injecting in my test `SyncedDOMModel`, uses a `WebSocket` which I bind in my module. When I am testing, I don't want to use a real websocket and server. So I want to overload that binding in my test, with a class that basically emulates the whole thing. It's easier to just inject a different implementation of the WebSocket in this case rather than use mocking.

If it helps, this is a basic outline of the SyncedDOMMOdel class:

```
public class SyncedDOMMOdel {
 ....
    @Inject
    public SyncedDOMModel(WebSocket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

 ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GinModuleAdapter` to use any `GinModule` as a Guice `Module`.

Obviously, you won't benefit from GIN's specific features: default to `GWT.create()` when something has no particular binding (this includes interfaces and abstract classes, which would throw in Guice), and automatically search for a `RemoteService` interface when an interface whose name ends `Async` has no specific binding.
And you won't be able to use anything that depends on JSNI or deferred binding (`GWT.create()`), as in any non-`GWTTestCase` unit test.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the guidance! I updated my post above with more details based on your suggestion. I feel like I am close but still not putting the whole thing together. Any more help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See updated answer. If I were you I'd set a breakpoint in the `GwtDotCreateProvider` (or another method in the callstack) to understand which class is missing an explicit binding. Note: it might possibly just be a class with a zero-arg constructor that's not annotated with `@Inject` (this is useless with Guice, but IIRC the absence of `@Inject` triggers `GWT.create(X.class)` rather than `new X()` with GIN)

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I was able to get this working after playing with it some more. With the GinModuleAdapter I can even get overrides working! Awesome.